# display textfield one by one in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

it is possible to display textfield one by one on button click.Means initially all textfields visibility is hidden But when button is click,Textfields Should be display one after one,property should be change to Visible??

Here is what i try so far

```
function myFunction() {

        for(var v=1;v<=4;v++){

            if(v==2){document.getElementById("b").style.visibility = "visible";}
            if(v==3){document.getElementById("c").style.visibility = "visible";}
            if(v==4){document.getElementById("d").style.visibility = "visible";}


        }
    }
```

it display all textfield when i click on button

Answer (score 1):

The following should do exactly what you want:

```js
function showFields() {
  // The following will only select the first hidden input element
  let nextHiddenInput = document.querySelector('div.textfields > input[class=hidden]');

  // Continue until no more hidden inputs are found
  if(nextHiddenInput)  {
    // Remove 'hidden' from its css classes
    nextHiddenInput.classList.remove('hidden');
    // 500 is the time it takes in millis for the next field to appear
    setTimeout(showFields, 500);
  }
}

// You could also use this function
function showFieldsAlternative() {
  function show(element) { // private method
     if(element) {
        element.classList.remove('hidden');
        /* If you remove the following line, an input will 
         appear every time you click on the button */
        setTimeout(show, 500, element.nextElementSibling);
     }
  }
  let firstHiddenInput = document.querySelector('div.textfields > input[class=hidden]');
  show(firstHiddenInput);
}

// Or using setInterval instead of setTimeout
function showFieldsUsingInterval() {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    let nextHiddenInput = document.querySelector('div.textfields > input[class=hidden]');
    if(nextHiddenInput) {
      nextHiddenInput.classList.remove('hidden')
    } else // Stop interval when no more hidden fields are found
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Textfield One by one</title>
      <style>
      .textfields > input {
        display: block;
        margin: 0.5em 0;
      }
      .hidden {
         display: none !important;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="textfields">
        <input type="text" class="hidden" />
        <input type="text" class="hidden" />
        <input type="text" class="hidden" />
        <input type="text" class="hidden" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="showFields()">Show Fields</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: yes this is what i am searching for thank you @DrunkenPoney

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to hide the fields initially and you want to display once the button is clicked. I have used jquery as you have tagged Jquery in your question.

```
<p class="hidden">
a
</p>
<p class="hidden">
b
</p>
<p class="hidden">
c
</p>
<p class="hidden">
d
</p>

<button id="button">
Click Me
</button>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#button").on('click',function() {
    $("p").removeClass('hidden')
  });
})
```

Here is the working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/awLs2uby/

Comment: I can't edit your post but you've duplicated the ending tag of button.

Comment: @DrunkenPoney Thanks bro for noticing it :)

Comment: And your javascript code will make all the `p` elements to appear at the same time but I think that what he want is to make them appear gradually with an interval between each of them.

Comment: He is not responding to the comments so i wasn't so clear what he is trying to achieve

Comment: yes i was trying to achieve what @DrunkenPoney posted to displaying textfield on button click

Comment: accept the correct answer a tick mark ill be shown and upvote the answers if it was helpful to you. btw welcome to stackoverflow community

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your solution isn't working is because:

Once you have made your first button click, your `for` loop will have already ended.
Hence the variable `v` would be equal to **4**

```
    // it will have changed from 1 through 4 already
```

This makes ALL your elements to display at once.

**SOLUTION:**

This *issue* can be resolved using [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

In a nutshell:
A **closure** is a function having access to the parent scope, even after the parent function has closed.

*EXAMPLE*

```
 var add = (function () {
var counter = 0;
return function () {return counter += 1;}
})();

add();
add();
add();

// the counter is now 3
```

*EXAMPLE EXPLAINED*

The variable `add` is assigned the return value of a self-invoking function.

The self-invoking function only runs once. It sets the counter to zero (0), and returns a function expression.

This way `add` becomes a function. The "wonderful" part is that it can access the `counter` in the parent scope.

This is called a *JavaScript closure*. It makes it possible for a function to have "private" variables.

*APPLICATION OF CLOSURES*

Check *JSFiddle* Here: https://jsfiddle.net/theAccountant/v5we76z3/12/

*HTML*

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="nextButton">NEXT</button>

<form>
  <div class="form-group" id="username">
    <label for="exampleInputUsername1">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUsername1" placeholder="Username">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group form1" id="email">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form1" id="password">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary form1">Submit</button>
</form>
```

*JS:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".form1").fadeOut();

  var add = (function() {
    var counter = 0;
    return function() {
      return counter += 1;
    }
  })();

  function addVisibility(counter) {
    switch (counter) {
      case 1:
        $("#email").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 2:
        $("#password").fadeIn();
        break;
      case 3:
        $("#submit").fadeIn();
        break;
      default:
    }
  }

  $("#nextButton").click(function() {
    addVisibility(add());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample example you can simply achieve this by setInterval function no need of loop.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <p id="1" style="display: none;">a</p>
 <p id="2" style="display: none;">b</p>
 <p id="3" style="display: none;">c</p>
 <p id="4" style="display: none;">d</p>
<script>
var i=1;
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById(i).style.display = "block";i++; if(i==4){clearInterval()}},1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```